# named query in JPA class

Tags: jpa

I am using Websphere 6.1 with JPA. I see that the Named Queries are always defined in a Data Entity Class. is it possible to define a Named Query outside a data entity class. If not, is there a way to get around this restriction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with annotations. But you can always define named query in XML descriptor.

According specification annotation can only be in entity or mapped superclass:

```
The NamedQuery and NamedQueries annotations can be applied to an entity or 
mapped superclass.
```